# UISlider setThumbImage, the thumb image isn't showing correctly on iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7, uislider

I am using:

`[pageSlider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UISliderThumb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

It works alright in iOS6 but for iOS7, the thumb image is under the progress bar, like so:

[image]

How do I get the thumb image to appear on the top like it should?

Bump: Anything?

Comment: Even I am getting the same problem. Can you please guide me if the slider is appearing properly

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding the thumb image first then u are adding minimum and maximum image for slider. You should first add minimum and maximum image for the slider then add Thumb image for the slider, See my below code.

```
       UIImage *trackLeftImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenvolume-slide.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 14, 0, 14)];
       [_globalSlider setMinimumTrackImage:trackLeftImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

       UIImage *trackRightImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"volume-slide.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 14, 0, 14)];
       [_globalSlider setMaximumTrackImage:trackRightImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       UIImage *ball = [UIImage imageNamed:@"volume-dragger.png"];
       [_globalSlider setThumbImage:ball forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code can help you :)

```
[pageSlider setThumbImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"UISliderThumb.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: hope you are not running on simulator

Comment: No, I am debugging on a device. Also, I don't see how running this in the simulator can have any different results.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and this doesn't solve it. Please explain why adding "imageWithRenderingMode" to UIImage would solve the OP (and mine) question.